# Question on Riemann's Derivation of Zeta Functional Equation

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, riemann-zeta

I am reading Bernhard Riemann's 1859 paper ["On the Number of Primes Less Than a Given Magnitude"](http://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/ezeta.pdf) in which he derives the Zeta functional equation through a [Hankel integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_contour) from $+\infty$ around the origin in a clockwise manner back to $+\infty$.

I am familiar with how he derives $$2sin(\pi s)\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)=i\int_{H} \frac{(-x)^{s-1}}{e^x-1}$$ but then he goes to say "If the real part of s is negative, then, instead of being taken in a positive
sense around the specified domain, this integral can also be taken in
a negative sense around that domain containing all the remaining complex
quantities, since the integral taken though values of infinitely large modulus
is then infinitely small. However, in the interior of this domain, the integrand
has discontinuities only where x becomes equal to a whole multiple of
±2πi, and the integral is thus equal to the sum of the integrals taken in a
negative sense around these values."

I know he makes use of the Residue Theorem, but I am more confused on how exactly does he reform the integral in order to have these values contained in the contour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\Re(s) < 0$  $$\int_H \frac{(-x)^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx= \int_B \frac{(-x)^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx$$ where $B$ is this contour

[image]

to which you can apply the residue theorem

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: @aleden This kind of contour is probably the way he came to the idea of Riemann surface, Riemann sphere..

Comment: I see, I was confused because he did not specify what kind of contour it was, so I believed it to be a standard Hankel contour.

Comment: @aleden Once you know the contour you see that's what he meant with " negative sense around that domain containing all the remaining complex quantities", no idea why he didn't draw it to make it clear